# The working principle of a recursive function

Tags: python, stack, depth-first-search

Dear
Thank you in advance.
My question is about DFS algorithm.
My code and result is as below.

1. code

```py
graph = [
    [],
    [2,3,8],
    [1,7],
    [1,4,5],
    [3,5],
    [3,4],
    [7],
    [2,6,8],
    [1,7]
]
visited = [False]*9

def dfs(graph, v, visited):
  visited[v] = True
  #print(v, end='')
  for i in graph[v]:
    print("i:",i,"v:",v)
    if not visited[i]:
      print("no")
      dfs(graph,i,visited)
```

2. result

```
i: 2 v: 1
no
i: 1 v: 2
i: 7 v: 2
no
i: 2 v: 7
i: 6 v: 7
no
i: 7 v: 6
i: 8 v: 7
no
i: 1 v: 8
i: 7 v: 8
i: 3 v: 1
no
i: 1 v: 3
i: 4 v: 3
no
i: 3 v: 4
i: 5 v: 4
no
i: 3 v: 5
i: 4 v: 5
i: 5 v: 3
i: 8 v: 1
```

3. my question
   I don't understand "the process of returning to the parent node when all connected nodes have been visited". For instance, node 6 only has one connected node, which is 7, and since we have already explored 7, shouldn't it just end without executing the statement under 'if not visited[i]'? I expected the exploration to finish after reaching 1-2-7-6 (i: 7 v: 7), but the result was different from my guess. I'm not sure why the next output is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit node 6 and that leads you to an already visited node 7 then that call to `dfs(graph, 6, visited)` does end. However, something called `dfs(graph, 6, visited)` and that something was the `for` loop of the prior call to `dfs(graph, 8, visited)`. Now that for loop will continue with the next item to check and so on...

Stepping through the code with a debugger make it much easier to understand. If you do I recommend setting watches on:

```
v
i
visited[v]
visited[i]
graph[v]
```